# Kindlepreviewer Command Not Found Mac Os X

Tags: kindle, amazon, mobi

I'm using some specialty software (Circular FLO) that requires use of the "kindlepreviewer" command in terminal, and any time it tries to do so, or if I try to do so myself, including "kindlepreviewer -help", it returns "command not found"

It' driving me absolutely bonkers, I can't seem to find this command anywhere on my computer manually either… my $PATH is returning /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin so that seems like it should be fine, but I searching any of those directories or the Kindle Previer 3 version 3.51.0 application package for the command turns up nothing.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here? Does anyone know where this command SHOULD be stored?

As alluded to above, I have Kindle Previewer 3 version 3.51.0 installed, and I'm running Mac OS Catalina. Any help at al would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow my usr/local/bin folder didn't exist at ALL on my work computer (not sure how IT set it up, but my personal computer had the folder and kindlepreviewer was in it after an install of Kindle Previewer 3). Manually creating a bin folder and doing an uninstall/reinstall of Kindle Previewer 3 created the command in the folder.